# Why 3 extra HTTP Requests are done if you use asp.Net Ajax call to a .net Web Service?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-ajax, xmlhttprequest

When I was reading the blog [Using jQuery to Consume ASP.NET JSON Web Services](http://encosia.com/2010/03/08/asmx-scriptservice-mistakes-installation-and-configuration/)

I have seen this argument:

"*By using jQuery to call the web service directly, we’ve eliminated over 100 KB of JavaScript and three extra HTTP requests.* "

Why does the ASP.NET AJAX call to a .NET Web-Service needs 3 extra HTTP requests? What are those requests? (I wonder how jQuery manages the call with lesser HTTP requests in this case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the best way to understand the difference is to download both examples and poke around at them yourself in Firebug, Fiddler, or similar.

These screenshots of the network traffic for both make it pretty clear though (both of these pages do exactly the same thing, one with jQuery and one with MicrosoftAjax.js):

Using MicrosoftAjax.js:

[image]

Using jQuery:

[image]

I'm not sure why the difference is only 90k now (but there's also an additional HTTP request too).  Something to do with the version of the MSAjax.js scripts served under 3.5/4.0 vs. the 2.0 ones I was using back when I wrote that, I think.

Even if your caching is configured correctly and those WebResource/ScriptResource scripts are cached, it's difficult to get the JS service proxy cached (`jsdebug` in the screenshot above), which you'll have to download once for every corresponding ASMX/WCF service you've referenced through the ScriptManager.  Those can get fairly large too (take a look at YourService.asmx/js or YourService.asmx/jsdebug to get an idea), whereas *no* service proxy is necessary for the jQuery approach.  That whole proxy exists simply to enable the `YourService.YourMethod()` calling syntax, vs. specifying the `YourService.asmx/YourMethod` path yourself.  The difference in convenience is negligible; not worth the overhead IMO.

Comment: Thank you very much Dave. Btw I appreciate your articles they really helped me a lot when i was practicing.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the author was referring to the requests needed to load the MS AJAX library itself. Hence the extra 100KB.

Comment: Then it should happen only once I believe not in all requests.

Comment: Indeed, the scripts should remain cached. But you still need to load them on initial page load.